# unable to import datasets on Mac in R

Tags: r, rstudio

```
library(tm)
library(tm.plugin.mail)
setwd("/Users/road/Test")
dir.selected <- "alt,atheism"
utils.precorpus <- function(dirName){
    corpus <- Corpus(DirSource(paste("data/20news-bydate/20news-bydate-test/",dirName,sep = "")),readerControl = list(reader = readMail,language=  "en_US"))
    names(corpus) <- dirName
    return (corpus)
}
```

> Error in DirSource(paste("data/20news-bydate/20news-bydate-test/", dirName, : empty directory

But when I use the `RStudio` on `Windows` to run this code,it can be run successfully. What's wrong with the directory?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Mac OS is based on Unix/Linux, you might need to add a leading "./" to specify that you want to start from the working directory.

```
corpus <- Corpus(DirSource(paste("./data/20news-bydate/20news-bydate-test/",dirName,sep = "")),readerControl = list(reader = readMail,language=  "en_US"))
```

Comment: Error in DirSource(paste("./data/20news-bydate/20news-bydate-test/", dirName,  : 
  empty directory